# PHP: Populating data in div

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to populate data in a div. Which works fine except that, the first div of data will be repeated once as shown on the attached image. I couldn't see any logical error in my code, and hope someone could kindly help me.

```
<div class="posts">
<?php
        include("dbconn.php");
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM posts p
                INNER JOIN users u
                ON p.userID=u.userID
                INNER JOIN courses c
                ON p.courseID=c.courseID;"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
                  <section class="post">
                    <header class="post-header"> <img class="post-avatar" height="48" width="48" src="image/common/tilo-avatar.png">
                        <h2 class="post-title"><?php echo $row["postTitle"]; ?></h2>
                        <p class="post-meta"> By <a href="#" class="post-author"><?php echo $row["nickname"]; ?></a> under <a class="post-category post-category-design" href="#"><?php echo $row["courseName"]; ?></a> </p>
                      </header>
                    <div class="post-description">
                        <p> <?php echo $row["postContent"]; ?> </p>
                    </div>
                </section>
<?php
            }
        } else {
            echo "no questions yet";
        }
?>
</div>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8mJM.png)

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting that repeated row from the database query?  It seems more likely that your data and/or query is incorrect than that somehow the PHP `while` implementation is broken...

Comment: at present according to your posted image, you have two records in your db, and you are repeating the first record twice!! right!!

Comment: what does the query produce when you run it in a mySql gui such as `heidi`? The `inner join`s look doubtful to me

Comment: Can you print_r($result) , and paste result here?

Comment: Oh god, Thank you for all your replies. I actually checked my database, and found a duplicate record. Can't believe I missed that out. >< Much Thanks !